# SQL Server Data Insert

Tags: sql-server

I have this query (dumping from another server)

```
CREATE TABLE [Reservation_reserve_room] (
  [id] int NOT NULL ,
  [reservation_id] int NULL ,
  [room_id] int NULL ,
  [room_name] varchar(255) NULL ,
  [reserve_date] date NULL ,
  [reserve_time_start] time(7) NULL ,
  [reserve_time_end] time(7) NULL 
)

INSERT INTO [Reservation_reserve_room] 
VALUES (N'1', N'1', N'1', N'Monday Room Sermmit', N'2012-03-12', 0x30373A30303A30302E30303030303030, 0x30383A30303A30302E30303030303030);
```

But when execute it, it has this error

> [Err] 42000 - [SQL Server]Implicit conversion from data type varbinary to time is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

How do i fix it?

Comment: "How do i fix it?" - Use the CONVERT function ...

Comment: `Use the CONVERT function to run this query.`. Simples.

Comment: What is `0x30373A30303A30302E30303030303030`? Milliseconds, seconds, something else?

Comment: When you're inserting into an `INT` column - just use the numerical value, e.g. `1` - don't convert your number to an `NVARCHAR` string (`N'1'`) and then back again - for nothing..... also: if you insert into a `VARCHAR` column (`room_name`) - do **NOT** use the `N'...'` prefix - again, your converting to `NVARCHAR` first (why???) and then SQL Server needs to convert back to `VARCHAR` since that's the columns datatype.....

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
CONVERT(time,CONVERT(varchar,0x30373A30303A30302E30303030303030))
```

good luck

Comment: I got Conversion failed when converting datetime from binary/varbinary string.

Comment: But I tested this before i post it and it works! I tested on MS SQL SERVER 2008 R2.

Answer (score 0):

The value you are entering into the table in time fields are not valid.

Use `Cast(Value as Time)` to convert into Time

```
INSERT INTO [Reservation_reserve_room] VALUES (N'1', N'1', N'1', N'Monday Room Sermmit',
N'2012-03-12', cast(0x30373A30303A30302E30303030303030 as  Time),
CAST( 0x30383A30303A30302E30303030303030 as  Time));
```

Comment: The question is how to fix it, not why are they getting the error.

Comment: This didnt really deserve a downvote, knowing why an error occurs is the first step in fixing it and understanding the solution.

Comment: @Ash Burlaczenko, Please let me know how can I convert invalid datetime to valid datetime from code.

Comment: Got Error: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: Try the query when you have valid data. Please let us know the source of this data.

Answer (score 0):

A time format I know is accepted in SQL always is '12 March 2012'.
This format is good for many DB types and doesn't confuse the date and the month numbers.

Answer (score 0):

use `CONVERT`

```
CONVERT(TIME, CONVERT(BIGINT, 0x30373A30303A30302E30303030303030))
```

OR Simply

```
CONVERT(TIME, 0x0000E0FF01E0FF01E0FF01E0FF01E0FF0100000000)


    INSERT INTO [Reservation_reserve_room] VALUES (N'1', N'1', N'1', N'Monday Room Sermmit', N'2012-03-12',  CONVERT(time, 0x30373A30303A30302E30303030303030)
,  CONVERT(time, 0x30373A30303A30302E30303030303030));
```

Read this Documentation on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

Comment: I get `Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime.`

Comment: what is 0x30373A30303A30302E30303030303030.

Comment: With your second/new query it throws `Conversion failed when converting datetime from binary/varbinary string.`

Comment: are you sure that the value stored in 0x30373A30303A30302E30303030303030 is datetime ?

Comment: see the edited answer ..i have changed datetime to time datatype